# Conditional rendering does not wait for axios data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What I am trying to do is fetch data with axios, and then set the data in state. Once that is over, I set the loading flag as false and conditionally render a child component in which I want to retrieve the properties of the first item of the array of the data.

Here is my custom hook code. I just fetch product data and set the data.

```
export const useAllProducts = () => {
  // const { showMessage } = useMessage();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<Product>>([]);

  const getProducts = useCallback(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get<Array<Product>>("http://localhost/api/admin/products")
      .then(res => setProducts(res.data))
      .catch(() =>
        console.log('failed to fetch product data')
      )
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return { getProducts, loading, products };
};
```

And here is my product page. After loading finishes, it renders the product list component with product data as props.

```
const ProductPage: React.FC = () => {
  const { getProducts, loading, products } = useAllProducts();
  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <CommonLayout title="product list">
      {!loading ?
        <ProductList title="product" data={products as Product[]} /> : 'loading'
      }
    </CommonLayout>
  );
}
export default ProductPage;
```

After this, in the product list component, I expected to be able to access the property names like this.

```
  const ProductList = <T,>(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>
) => {
  console.log(props)
  const classes = useStyles();
  Object.keys(props.data[0])

  return (
    <div>
      a
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, it gave me an error as below.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.keys ()
> at ProductList (app.js:12755)
> at renderWithHooks (app.js:33809)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (app.js:36488)
> at beginWork (app.js:37602)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:19194)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:19243)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:19298)
> at beginWork$1 (app.js:42209)
> at performUnitOfWork (app.js:41160)

I even checked the length of the data first, but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea of why conditional rendering is not working?

**edit1**

Here is my changed custom hook code after the comments. The logic seems to be fine..

```
export const useAllProducts = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Array<Product>>([]);

  const getProducts = useCallback(() => {
    axios
      .get<Array<Product>>("http://localhost/api/admin/products")
      .then(res => {
        setProducts(res.data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        console.log(error)
      )
  }, []);

  return { getProducts, loading, products };
};
```

**edit:2**

my simplified Product List component code.

```
const ProductList = <T, >(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props<T>>
) =>{
  console.log(props)
  const classes = useStyles();
  Object.keys(props.data[0])
  //The error is happening here//
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!loading ? <ProductList /> : "loading"`?

Comment: Ah sorry, I changed it to !loading,  but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Your condition should be `loading ? "Loading":
        <ProductList title="product" data={products as Product[]} /> 
      }`

Comment: I think I know the problem, the default `loading` value is `false` so it throws that error because the `products` is still empty when the component is created, try set it to `true` like this `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`

Comment: Remove `setLoading` false from `finally` block. In case there is an error, still the component renders.

Comment: @Medi this seems to be the right pattern, no matter what happens -- error or data, you must set `loading` as false because loading is done with or without the error. To handle the error you have `catch` block which the OP can see in console.

Comment: @Nishat, he needed to replace it with some error text indicating the problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I really appreciate it.

I changed my state code to `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);`

Also, I removed setLoading false from the finally block, and checked the length of the array. However, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Could you paste a simplified version of `ProductList`, the error is happening there, right?

Comment: Okay, I updated my post and pasted the error part.

Comment: @kappa updated the answer

Comment: I figured it out, the api data had one level deeper nest, that was why. 
Thank for being patient and giving me a lot of advice.

Answer (score 2):

This line seems to have the problem

```
loading 
  ? <ProductList title="product" data={products as Product[]} /> 
  : 'loading'
```

You are showing the product list when `loading` is true. It should be the other way

```
loading 
  ? 'loading'
  : <ProductList title="product" data={products as Product[]} />
```

Also, it is nice to check if product has some valid values

like

```
loading || !products
  ? 'loading'
  : <ProductList title="product" data={products as Product[]} />
```

Or even better,

In your `ProductList` check if `data` is null or undefined and show the user a notice that `No product found`. Just a better UX, I think.

---

Alright, so this is the issue

```
Object.keys(props.data[0])
```

Now, guess what happens when `data = []`? `data[0]` is `undefined`. It is not an object, it is undefined.

```
data = []; Object.keys(data[0])
VM633:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:19
```

A better approach is (assuming, in reality, you'd want to render the items by iterating them).

```
data.map(d => console.log(Object.keys(d)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the last one, and It still gave me the error
app.js:12755 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

It seems the component does not wait for the data to load for some reason.

Comment: You need to define the props in your ProductList as as `{title: string, data: Product[] | null | undefined}` and handle accordingly. This will fix the type error. Since it is localhost, it must be really fast.. you can use Chrome DevTools to set Network as Slow 3G to see if the network call is happening and what data is being return and also rendering.

Comment: `product` array is always truthy value, even if the array is empty. You check the length of the array.

Comment: @Medi oh, right. Good catch. The default is an empty array. Thanks for pointing that out.